# prioritise jquery events

Tags: jquery, events, live

[Please have a look at this script.](http://jsfiddle.net/sikko/BfEfX/)

Here is my problem:
I want both events to be fired by the click event.
The thing is one of them returns false, what logically makes jquery ignore the second one (and I need it to return false).

Any idea how I can achieve this ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You don't need to `click` inside of `each`.

Comment: e.preventDefault() and e.stopPropagation() behaved the same as return false.
I followed jfriend00 advice and used only one handler. Not the solution I expected but this solved my problem. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `return false`, call `e.preventDefault()`.
`return false` is equivalent to both `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use two separate click event handlers?  You could just put two function calls in one click handler.

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.stopPropagation()` 
http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/